# Переходы на другой fragment через item в шторке

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно сделать переходы через кнопки, которые по умолчанию в шторке. При этом я почистил проект чуть раньше, и теперь они никуда не ведут.

Comment: Вы не можете на кнопку действие повесить или сам переход на фрагмент осуществить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Знаете... вопрос МАКСИМАЛЬНО непонятный. Нет кода, нет конкретики, одна абстракция. А посему, ответ тоже будет немного лишен конкретики (но не так как у вас конечно). Для того чтобы осуществлять переходы по менюшке создадим ресурс меню:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_first_fragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_one"
            android:title="First" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_second_fragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_two"
            android:title="Second" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_third_fragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_three"
            android:title="Third" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Для того чтобы фрагменты могли где-то показываться и где-то существовать необходимо создать контейнер для этих целей:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

в этой разметке фигурирует тулбар:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

после того как мы создали все необходимые ресурсы, займемся активностью:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private NavigationView nvDrawer;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

а теперь собственно само переключение фрагментов:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass;
        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
                fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_second_fragment:
                fragmentClass = SecondFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_third_fragment:
                fragmentClass = ThirdFragment.class;
                break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }
```

Вот [первоисточник-туториал](https://guides.codepath.com/android/fragment-navigation-drawer).